QField crashes on iPhone when opening a QFieldCloud Project
I am setting up QField projects for crew leaders on our forestry crews, and one of them has an iPhone, and QField crashes every time he tries to open a QFieldCloud project from QField on his iPhone.
The details of the phone are:
Model: iPhone 13
Version: iOS 17.5.1
QField opens as normal. The QField Projects List opens as normal. When selecting a project to open from the QFieldCloud section, the app crashes.
Closed all other apps and restarted the phone. The same problems occurs. Uninstalled/reinstalled QField on the iPhone and attempted the same steps. The same problem occurs.
What could be the problem here and what is the best way to solve this?
